Weighted Sobolev space embedding
I am studying embedding about weighted Sobolev spaces $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n,w)$
Context:
Let $s_0>s_1,\, 1<p_0\leq p_1<\infty$ and $w_0\in A_{p_0},\, w_1\in A_{p_1}$ Muckenhoupt weights. If
\begin{align}
\sup_{\eta\in\mathbb{N},m\in\mathbb{Z}^n}2^{-\eta (s_0-s_1)}\frac{1}{\left(\int_{Q_{\eta,m}}w_0(x)\,dx\right)^{1/p_0}}\left(\int_{Q_{\eta,m}}w_1(x)\,dx\right)^{1/p_1}<\infty
\end{align}
where $Q_{\eta,m}$ is a $n$-cube (with sides parallel to coordinate axis) with center in $2^{-\eta}m$ and sides of lenght $2^{-\eta}$ then
\begin{align}
H^{s_0,p_0}(\mathbb{R}^d,w_0)\hookrightarrow H^{s_1,p_1}(\mathbb{R}^d,w_1)
\end{align}
Reference: theorem 1.3 in 1 M. Meyries, and M. Veraar, “Characterization of a class of embeddings for function spaces with Muckenhoupt weights,” Arch. Math. 103(5), 435–449 (2014)
Question: Why can't $s_0$ be equal to $s_1$? Or is it also possible?
Thanks.

Is the embedding continuous or compact?

Is continuous....
